# Auth.net completed transactions showing as Pending (Incomplete Transaction) - sometimes

Tags: contribution-page, authorize.net, pending

CiviCRM: 4.7.17
Joomla 3.6.5

This does not happen every time, seems random. New Member Online registration - Contribution goes through to Auth.Net and is marked there as successful/completed, but the contribution record in Civi is marked as Pending (Incomplete Transaction) and the Membership stays in the status of pending.
Following is an example of what I find in the civi error logs each time this occurs. Could somebody help me determine what the cause of this could be?

```
Log 1:
```

Apr 10 15:28:31  [info] Contribution record updated successfully

Apr 10 15:28:35  [info] Receipt sent

Apr 10 15:28:35  [info] Success: Database updated

```
Log 2:
```

Apr 10 15:28:31  [info] Could not find an entry for x_subscription_id

Apr 10 15:28:31  [info] $error data = Array
(

```
[error_code] => 0
```

)

Apr 10 15:28:31  [info] $REQUEST = Array
(

```
[x_response_code] => 1

[x_response_reason_code] => 1

[x_response_reason_text] => This transaction has been approved.

[x_avs_code] => Y
```

...

)

Answer (score 1):

There were some issues with Authorize.net transactions failing due it not managing to send an email- could that be related? Is email always required on the page? I think there are a.net fixes in both 4.7.18 & 4.7.19 (still in rc) so it might be worth checking if a point upgrade changes anything (4.7.19 is due out first Wed next month)

Comment: Thanks. Email is required in the form and it appears that the emails are being sent. The response from Auth indicates the transaction was approved and there are no errors. In fact the log entries I added are the same entries I see for a successful transaction that goes through as completed. I'm unable to find a related issue that resembles this behavior, but will try updating to see if it helps.